# Communication between threads with a waiting time limit

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my C++ game program, how do I write a function that accepts an input per turn from a bot running on a separate thread? The function should update the game state immediately upon receiving the input but will wait no more than x seconds.

I am aware of conditional variables but is not aware of how to set a time limit for the thread that is waiting on the bot?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for pthread_cond_timedwait() ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html )

Comment: In modern c++ you have [`std::condition_variable::wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for)

Comment: If your program is running under Windows, WaitForMultipleObjects is brilliant. In u*ix you have select() - or poll (or epoll or BSD's flipaswitch in shmem) to wait on event on file descriptors. The C++11 threading lib isn't written to accomodate all the programming flavours in this regard. Hate to say it, but the Win32 API gave programming users a better interface. To the question: The threading support in standard (>=11) C++ provides all you need - but the Windows interface is much easier to use to make good threading. (ok, now I will get burned)

Comment: Are you targeting  a particular platform? It sounds like there are lots of  options,  but  some may be more readily  available than others. (I  was going to suggest semaphores and something like `dispatch_semaphore_wait()`, for example, on iOS and macOS.)

Comment: I am targeting Linux

Comment: @TedLyngmo the real beauty is when you can use `select` and inheritors or Overlapped IO to completely eliminate threads and get a simple state machine.